# Lost precision while filling double[] array via For statement

Tags: c#, arrays, precision

I need to resolve the math expression in array [0.1;1.7] with the precision of 0.00001.

I created double[] array and tried to fiil it via For statement with step = 0.00001 but after 43rd iteration in the end of the value I get extra "1":
0,00043
0,000440000000000001
0,000450000000000001
0,000460000000000001
and in the end of the cycle there is a visible difference between a true value and a recieved like 1,7000000000000000246

The same behavior with the float[] array.

```
for (double i = 0.00001; i <= 1.7; i=i+.00001)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: You are outside the precision of floating point numbers.  A number is stored as a binary number (base 2) and due to the conversion from decimal to base 2 and back the you cannot get every value exactly.  You would need to truncate the number by rounding to drop the extra 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You are outside in double precision.The number is stored as a binary due to which conversion from base 10 to binary and back then you cannot get every value exact. 
    **Solution**
    1.In this case either you have to truncate the number by rounding to drop the extra 1.

    2. use "**decimal**" datatype. 
    If you use decimal it will me more precise.



for (double i = 0.00001; i <= 1.7; i=i+.00001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```